# How to solve selenium webdriver: ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable in nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I started to learn Selenium

but i'm stuck trying to upload and download on a element like this:

I want to upload a dwg file on [this site](https://products.aspose.app/cad/text-extractor/dwg) and convert it into a text file. So I'm using selenium.

I encountered a problem while uploading the file

This is my error message:

[image]

We have tried several solutions to this problem.

1. ADD driver.manage().window().maximize();
2. use click() instead of sendKeys()
3. Check Element is Enabled

However, no solution has solved the problem.
This is the entire code:

```
const { Builder, Browser, By, Key, until } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const chromeDriver = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
const chromeOptions = new chromeDriver.Options();

const chromeExample = async () => {
  const driver = await new Builder()
    .forBrowser(Browser.CHROME)
    .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions.headless())
    .build();

  driver.manage().window().maximize();

  await driver.get("https://products.aspose.app/cad/text-extractor/dwg");

  await driver.wait(
    until.elementLocated(By.className("filedrop-container width-for-mobile")),
    10 * 1000
  );

  await driver.wait(
    until.elementIsEnabled(
      driver.findElement(By.className("filedrop-container width-for-mobile"))
    ),
    10 * 1000
  );

  const tmp = await driver
    .findElement(By.className("filedrop-container width-for-mobile"))
    .sendKeys("/home/yeongori/workspace/Engineering-data-search-service/macro/public/images/testfile1.dwg");
  console.log(tmp);
};
```

The same error occurs when i change the code as below.
await driver
.findElement(By.className("filedrop-container width-for-mobile"))
.sendKeys(Key.ENTER);

One strange thing is that if i change sendKeys to click and check tmp with console.log, it is null.

This is Project Directory

[image]

How can I solve this problem? I'm sorry if it's too basic a question. But I'd be happy if there was any hint. Thank you.

WSL2(Ubuntu-20.04), Node.js v18.12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `sendKeys` on the `input` element which is nested deeper in the element that you are currently trying to send keys to.

You can reach the element with this xpath:

```
"//*[contains(@id,'UploadFileInput')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a checkbox, I have solved by sendKeys(Key.SPACE)